# Trying to separate a txt file into two ArrayLists?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

[This image is a text file I need to separate by date and the digits alongside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUFNC.png)

```
BufferedReader wordReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\Users\\rosha\\eclipse-workspace\\working\\src\\workingfix\\spx_data_five_years.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> spxIndex = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<>();
        //populating the Array with the file
        String line = wordReader.readLine();
        
        while (line != null) {
            date.add(line);
            line = wordReader.readLine();
        }
        wordReader.close();
```

Would really love to understand how to separate this file into two Arrays. Been at it for a while and some Guidance in the right direction would be incredible. Apologies if it's a simple solution for some reason I'm having trouble getting started.

Here is the some of the Text File, if I can get guidance on this I'll be in good shape

1/4/2010    1132.99

1/5/2010    1136.52

1/6/2010    1137.14

1/7/2010    1141.69

1/8/2010    1144.98

1/11/2010   1146.98

1/12/2010   1136.22

1/13/2010   1145.68

Comment: please provide the sample input as text and not an image. Hint: use regex or StringTokenizer or simply String.split()

Answer (score 0):

Your two examples are a little bit different, in the Image, it seems like the entries are separated by a tab. In your text example, the entries are separated by a space. If they are separated by a space, a simple `String[] splitter = line.split(" ");` suffices. This gives you the result as an Array, which you can write in the ArrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, using **split** method

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> spxIndex = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<>();
    String sCurrentLine;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\Users\\rosha\\eclipse-workspace\\working\\src\\workingfix\\spx_data_five_years.txt"));
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lineValues = sCurrentLine.split(" "); 
        date.add(lineValues[0]); 
        spxIndex.add(lineValues[1]); 
    }
    br.close();
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(spxIndex);
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an "Index 1 out of bounds for length 1" error. Anyway to remedy this?

Comment: Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: 1/4/2010    1132.99
1/5/2010    1136.52
1/6/2010    1137.14
1/7/2010   1141.69
1/8/2010   1144.98

Comment: Within the text file there is 4 spaces between the date and the numerical digits

Comment: use trim to remove white spaces example 
lineValues[0].trim()
lineValues[1].trim()